# Should I make separated commits for an every creation of a new file in working directory (e.g. styles.scss, index.js etc)?

Tags: git

I am currently learning GIT and trying to create some web projects using it. 
However I am not sure how to make proper commits when creating a new file: 
e.g. I made the initial commit and then added **index.js** to my working directory. 
Should I commit this empty file as **"Index.js is created"**? Like is it enough change to make a whole commit? 
Will appreciate your help a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would answer your question with "no". The purpose of making commits is to bundle changes to your application's code in light of working towards a feature.

The addition of a file is *a* step towards a new feature, yes, but not a meaningful one.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is important for me to understand)

Answer (score 1):

When I first started learning git, I found that physically writing out common git actions on sticky notes and putting them onto my cork board was a great help.  It forced me to read and understand, and to actually type out the git command in git-bash from scratch each time.  That gave me the muscle memory I needed to do a normal cadence for checking out new feature branches, committing them, pushing them and merging and rebasing.  These are the normal day to day things I do with git.  I get occasional things I need to do as well, and the best thing I've found is beginner youtube videos and other git tutorials.  The git manual is definitive, but it is hard to use, because it has every possible way to use a git command when all you want to do is "git it done" and "git back to codeing".

That said, coding involves a lot of files.  You have configuration files in XML, json or yaml, style files in css, scss etc.  code files in .js, .jsx, .cs, .vb or whatever, and they all work together to do whatever it is you are trying to achieve.

If you had to do a commit every time you created a new file, then you would be spinning your wheels fiddling with git, instead of making money coding.  So your suspicion is correct - committing every time you make a new file is a pain.

**So to answer your question**, you can commit as often as you would like, but typically you want to do it when you actually achieve something... For example:

- You finish that one js file and its related css file, and you've
  added a new library that made your packages file change.
- You have a new test that works.
- You changed/added one or more files to fix that ugly error screen your users get.
- It is the end of the day, and you are not finished with what you are doing, and you just want to commit what you have with something as simple as `git commit -am "WIP - left
  off with new login page changes that don't work yet"' and leave it
  for the following week so that you can come here and answer questions
  for people :)

But there is more to it than committing, of course.  You have to be safe.

Committing should be followed up with 'git push' to get it somewhere safe just in case your computer reverts to some checkpoint from last June (Happened to me last week.  So glad I push a lot and I only lost 1 day of work)

There are many opinions on what a good commit comment is, so if mine seem lame, then google for better ideas.  But the point is, no, you don't have to commit every time you make a new file.  But you should after you have achieved some kind of goal.

example:
Maybe you have a detailed task list to work from like Jira, so every time you finish a task, reference that task# in your commit message, and all the files you changed will be bundled up together for that task, and it will be tidy - and a year from now you will be able to look back and piece it together with no trouble if you need to.

git is complicated, and timtowtdi holds true and sticky notes only go so far.  I'm on a mac, and I use the notes app a lot, and one page is dedicated to new things I learn about git and how to do stuff.
Here are some of the topics I have:

- "Steps for making a release candidate" with explanations of how we do
  it and what happens when we do, along with a bunch of non-git related
  stuff. "Stashing" - how it works, and how it works for me.  that is,
  creating one, and popping it back.  I use this several times a week.
- "Creating and checking out a new branch" - but not only that, but
  what to type to push it to the origin repo the first time.
- "Rebasing"

  - what I do when I merge another feature branch into the development branch, and I want my current feature branch to have it too.
- "Merging" - I don't use it a lot, but other people I work closely
  with do, and it is great to know what this is and how to use it and
  when.
- "Undoing a single file" - every make a change to a file and
  wish you could start over?  This is where I have the notes on how to
  do that
- "Undoing all changes" - ever had a bad day with bad ideas,
  and you want to start all over again?
- "Fetch another branch other
  than the one you are on" - for when you are on the current branch but
  you don't want to do all that flipping back and forth between
  branches to be sure things are pulled down from origin

These topics and more are at my fingertips when I need them, and are basically the results of the research I've done here on SO, and elsewhere.  They are kind of like a blog to myself that no one else will ever see, and that makes sense only to me.

I hope these tips help you.

Answer (score -2):

you have to add that file before committing.

Steps:

1. Create index.js file.
2. add that file or changes.
3. commit that changes with an appropriate message.
4. push it to git